# xml multi level to csv using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, parent-child

I have an XML like this:

```
 <PROGRAM>
    <date>10/07/2014</date>
    <name>Name</name>
    <LOTS>
        <LOT>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <type>A</type>
        </LOT>
        <LOT>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <type>B</type>
        </LOT>
</PROGRAM>
```

And I'd like to get this from the transformation (XSLT) result:

10/07/2014,Name,1,A 
10/07/2014,Name,2,B

here is my xslt :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name='newline'>
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//LOT">
            <xsl:for-each select="//PROGRAM">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(date,',',name)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',ID,',',type,$newline)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Does anyone know the XSLT to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something simpler:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="PROGRAM/LOTS/LOT">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(../../date, ',', ../../name, ',', ID, ',', type)"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```